# Proper distance in terms of the deceleration parameter

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, distance, redshift

So, in an effort to connect theory to measurable quantities, in the Ryden cosmology textbook the scale factor is Taylor expanded as $$a(t) \approx 1 + H_o (t-t_o) - \frac{1}{2}q_o H^2_o (t-t_o)^2$$ and $$\frac{1}{a(t)}\approx 1 - H_o(t-t_o) + (1+\frac{q_o}{2})H^2_o (t-t_o)^2$$.

Plugging $\dfrac{1}{a(t)}$ into proper distance calculation $$d_p(t_o) = c\int_{t_e}^{t_o}\dfrac{dt}{a(t)}$$ we get to keep only the two lowest order terms $d_p(t_o) \approx c(t_o - t_e) + \dfrac{cH_o}{2}(t_o - t_e)^2$.

Since $t_o - t_e$ is not directly measurable,  we replace it in terms of $z$ making use of $z = \dfrac{1}{a(t_e)}-1$, from which we get $t_o - t_e \approx \dfrac{1}{H_o}\left[z - (1 + q_o / 2)z^2\right]$.

Finally, plugging $t_o - t_e \approx \dfrac{1}{H_o}[z - (1 + q_o / 2)z^2]$ into $d_p(t_o) \approx c(t_o - t_e) + \dfrac{cH_o}{2}(t_o - t_e)^2$, we get $$d_p(t_o) \approx \frac{cz}{H_0}[1- \frac{1+q_o}{2}z]$$
if we only keep up to $z^2$. But what I don't understand is here in the last step why only keep up to $z^2$? Does this mean this whole derivation only applies to low z? Then what's the point since we know it's linear at low z anyway?

Comment: If the first step was to Taylor expand $a(t)$ and retain terms only up to second order, then yes, the whole derivation only applies to cosmologically small time intervals, i.e. to low redshifts. I would have to know the context of the derivation to know what the point is.

Answer (score 0):

In short: yes, it's because the formula is only valid at low redshifts, so higher-order terms are insignificant; the measurement of $q_0$ tells you about the composition of the universe.

---

First off, you have to understand that $q_0$ is more of a historical artifact than a commonly used parameter nowadays; see Ryden's text right after eqn 7.6 (on page 127–128 in [the online version](http://carina.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/extragalactica/Bibliografia/Ryden_IntroCosmo.pdf)). Why do we only keep up to $z^2$? Because this derivation only applies to low redshifts. At small enough ranges, all (sane) functions are linear, so this shouldn't be surprising or mean that this derivation was useless.

Secondly, the reason why this slope is useful is because its value tells us about the composition of the universe. See eqns 7.10 / 7.11 in the same text (page 129):
$$ q_0 = \Omega_{r,0} + \frac{1}{2} \Omega_{m,0} - \Omega_{\Lambda,0}$$
Because we only really measure $q_0$ at low redshift (generally $z<2$; roughly $z \sim 10$ is where radiation density started being insignificant in comparison to dark energy density; $\Omega_{r,0} \sim 10^{-4}$), we can then simplify this for the modern era, as all that contribute significantly are the last two terms:
$$ q_0 = \frac{1}{2} \Omega_{m,0} - \Omega_{\Lambda,0}$$
Because people used to expect that the majority of energy in the universe was matter, followed by radiation, they defined $q_0$ in such a way that they expected $q_0$ to have a positive value. It was quite the shock then the first measurements of $q_0$ yielded negative numbers! A recent measurement by [Riess et al 2021](https://doi.org/10.3847/2041-8213/ac5c5b) accounting for a host of potential systematic effects found that $q_0 = -.51 \pm -.024$, over $20\sigma$ significantly negative! This is conclusive evidence that (insofar as GR is to be trusted as a theory of gravity) we live in a universe with a non-trivial amount of dark energy—in fact, in a universe currently dominated by dark energy!

Thirdly, I'll give a bit more detail about why the derivation stops at $z^2$. People have gone beyond (see [Vissier 2004](https://doi.org/10.1088/0264-9381/21/11/006) for jerk $j_0$ and snap $s_0$ definitions), but most cosmologists focus on cosmological parameters (like $\Omega_m$, $\Omega_\Lambda$) directly rather than Taylor coefficients which only relate indirectly to cosmological parameters. Furthermore, the higher-order terms become harder to measure significantly, so what *can* be learned from them about our universe is limited.